# Command line tool to check music/video urls, my browser connected to

Tags: shell, unix, network-programming, command

I know, how to check it with Chrome's inspector and Firebug via networking tab, but I'd like to know is it possible to use something like tcpdump/netstat/lsof to check the url of stream's being played?  Also, is it possible to find out all the downloading urls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing `-X` to `tcpdump` will cause it to dump some of each packet in ASCII form, but something smarter such as Wireshark (TShark) would be better.